# Script to convert Huge Three column table into table

Tags: python, r, algorithm, scripting, import-from-csv

I have a set of data (CSV files) in the following 3 column format:

```
A, B, C
3277,4733,54.1 
3278,4741,51.0 
3278,4750,28.4 
3278,4768,36.0 
3278,4776,50.1 
3278,4784,51.4 
3279,4792,82.6 
3279,4806,78.2 
3279,4814,36.4
```

And I need to get a three-way contingency table like: (sorry, this doesn't look completely good)

```
A /B     4733      4741      4750      4768      4776      4784      4792      4806      4814
3277   C 54.1                                                
3278                 51      28.4        36      50.1      51.4                  
3279                                                                 82.6      78.2      36.4
```

Similarly to an excel "pivot table", OpenOffice data pilot, or R "table(x,y,z)"

The problem is that my dataset is HUGE (more than 500,000 total rows, with about 400 different factors in A and B. (OOo, MSO and R limits prevent from achieving this)

I am sure a Python script could be used to create such a table. both A and B are numbers (but can be treated as strings).

Anyone has dealt with this? 
(pseudocode or code in C or Java is also welcomed ... but I prefer python as it is faster to implement :)

**Edit:** 
Almost have it, thanks to John Machin. The following Python script *almost* provides what I am looking for, however, when writing the output file I can see that the values in the "headers" I am writing (taken from the first row) do not correspond to the other rows.

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
d = dd(lambda: dd(float))

input =  open("input.txt")
output = open("output.txt","w")
while 1:
    line = input.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    line = line.strip('\n').strip('\r')
    splitLine = line.split(',')
    if (len(splitLine) <3):
        break
    d[splitLine[0]][splitLine[1]] = splitLine[2]

output.write("\t")
for k,v in d.items()[0][1].items():
    output.write(str(k)+"\t")
output.write("\n")
for k,v in d.items():
    output.write(k+"\t")
    for k2,v2 in v.items():
        output.write(str(v2)+"\t")
    output.write("\n")
```

Comment: Consider using a numpy array, it's optimized for larger datasets http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-d3f8e5fe9b903f3c3b2a5c0dfceb60d71602cf93

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the 3-way nature of this problem. Isn't your table just Z where Z[A,B] = C? And if you have 400 factors for A and B then Z is only 400*400. Are you averaging over identical A,B pairs? I'm missing a third dimension here. Much like roadkill.

Comment: Yes, sorry my description was wrong. I only need a mapping of the 3 column table to the row/column/value table. Ideally I need a script with takes a CSV file with A,B,C and write the same data in the shown tabular format.

Comment: So your output matrix is really 3D, as Z[A,B,C], with no value stored in Z[A,B,C], it just exists? Still not clear. It might be easier to tell us what you want to do with this and then we could find a better solution. Obviously you dont want to print it out....

Comment: Well... actually the idea of doing the conversion is to "present" the data in this specific way. Think of A,B,C as a graph where A and B are the two nodes and C is the "label" of the arc between the nodes. The idea is to present the data in form of a Matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whole new story deserves a whole new answer.

Don't need defaultdict, don't even want defaultdict, because using it carelessly would suck memory like the Death Star's tractor beam.

This code is untested, may not even compile; I may have swapped rows and columns somewhere; fixes/explanations later ... must rush ...

```
d = {}
col_label_set = set()
row_label_set = set()
input =  open("input.txt")
output = open("output.txt","w")
for line in input:
    line = line.strip()
    splat = line.split(',')
    if len(splat) != 3:
        break # error message???
    k1, k2, v = splat
    try:
        subdict = d[k1]
    except KeyError:
        subdict = {}
        d[k1] = subdict
    subdict[k2] = v
    row_label_set.add(k1)
    col_label_set.add(k2)
col_labels = sorted(col_label_set)
row_labels = sorted(row_label_set
output.write("\t")
for v in col_labels::
    output.write(v + "\t")
output.write("\n")
for r in row_labels:
    output.write(r + "\t")
    for c in col_labels:
        output.write(d[r].get(c, "") + "\t")
    output.write("\n")
```

**Update** Here's a fixed and refactored version, tested to the extent shown:

```
class SparseTable(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        d = {}
        col_label_set = set()
        for row_label, col_label, value in iterable:
            try:
                subdict = d[row_label]
            except KeyError:
                subdict = {}
                d[row_label] = subdict
            subdict[col_label] = value
            col_label_set.add(col_label)
        self.d = d
        self.col_label_set = col_label_set

    def tabulate(self, row_writer, corner_label=u"", missing=u""):
        d = self.d
        col_labels = sorted(self.col_label_set)
        row_labels = sorted(d.iterkeys())
        orow = [corner_label] + col_labels
        row_writer(orow)
        for row_label in row_labels:
            orow = [row_label]
            subdict = d[row_label]
            for col_label in col_labels:
                orow.append(subdict.get(col_label, missing))
            row_writer(orow)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    test_data = u"""
    3277,4733,54.1
    3278,4741,51.0
    3278,4750,28.4
    3278,4768,36.0
    3278,4776,50.1
    3278,4784,51.4
    3279,4792,82.6
    3279,4806,78.2
    3279,4814,36.4
    """.splitlines(True)

    def my_writer(row):
        sys.stdout.write(u"\t".join(row))
        sys.stdout.write(u"\n")

    def my_reader(iterable):
        for line in iterable:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line: continue
            splat = line.split(u",")
            if len(splat) != 3:
                raise ValueError(u"expected 3 fields, found %d" % len(splat))
            yield splat

    table = SparseTable(my_reader(test_data))
    table.tabulate(my_writer, u"A/B", u"....")
```

Here's the output:

```
A/B     4733    4741    4750    4768    4776    4784    4792    4806    4814
3277    54.1    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....
3278    ....    51.0    28.4    36.0    50.1    51.4    ....    ....    ....
3279    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    82.6    78.2    36.4
```

Comment: Yay! you are my hero today. Yep, this works like acharm (just after some minor corrections :: and a missing )  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @xtracto: I'm glad I could help. Please leave a comment about the minor corrections and I'll tidy the answer up in the morning (it's sleep time in this TZ) so we don't leave a buggy non-compiling answer for other people to stumble over.

Answer (score 1):

When all you have is a hammer . . . . .

Conceptually, what you are trying to do is simple but because of the size of your data, it is computationally difficult. I tend to use R for it's analytic and graphics capacity, not it's data wrangling skills. When I need to move around a bunch of data, I usually just stick everything into a database.

Lately I have had quite a bit of success with SQLite and R. The best part is that you can actually use R to read in your data, which makes it easy to import large SPSS files or other sources of data that SQLite can't really handle but R can.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html

Here's my recommended work flow.

1. Import your data into R. (Done)
2. Library(RSQLite)
3. Move your data frame to SQLite.
4. Create Indexes on columns A and B.
5. Create a view that builds your table.
6. Query your view from R and coerce the returns into a table.

Comment: Another nice aspect of dumping all your data into SQLite - Once your data is in SQLite you can easily use Python or Perl to play with your data. You can even use other tools like SOFA Statistics. Connectivity with SQLite is very widespread. In contrast, data stored in R's native data structures are not easily accessible to other programming languages or tools.

Answer (score 1):

In R I can do this:

```
N <- 1000000
x <- sample(1:400,N,TRUE)
y <- sample(1:400,N,TRUE)
z <- sample(1:400,N,TRUE)

w <- table(x,y,z)
```

And memory peak is lower then 800MB.

So what limitations you have?

---

EDIT. This peace of R-code:

```
N <- 1000000
mydata <- data.frame(
    A=sample(runif(400),N,TRUE),
    B=sample(runif(400),N,TRUE),
    C=runif(N)
)

require(reshape)
results <- cast(mydata, A~B, value="C")
write.table(as.matrix(results),na="",sep="\t",file="results.txt")
```

create what you want with less then 300MB of RAM.

On my data it gives warning cause there are non-unique A-B combinations but for yours should be ok.

Comment: Those are all integer vectors.  Does it still work if you convert to numeric?

Comment: @Joshua I replace `1:400` with `rnorm(400)` and it still works. It use more RAM ~1.1GB.

Comment: This was tested with a *partial* set of my data:  summary(mydata)
> names(mydata)
[1] "A"   "B"     "C"
> nrow(mydata)
[1] 180227
newtab<-table(mydata$A, mydata$B, mydata$C)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb
>

Answer (score 0):

If you could use `table(x,y,z)` in R, then how about trying out the R out of memory packages that handle such huge data sets? Use the `read.big.matrix` function in the package [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/) to read in the data set and the `bigtable` function in the package [bigtabulate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigtabulate/index.html) to create the table.

See [vignettes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/vignettes/Overview.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Your example of desired output doesn't look like a 3-way contingency table to me. That would be a mapping from (key1, key2, key3) to a count of occurences. Your example looks like a mapping from (key1, key2) to some number. *You don't say what to do when (key1, key2) is duplicated: average, total, something else?*

Assuming that you want a total, here's one memory-saving approach in Python, using nested `defaultdict`s:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict as dd
>>> d = dd(lambda: dd(float))
>>> d[3277][4733] += 54.1
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x00D61DF0>, {3277: defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {4733: 54.1})})
>>> d[3278][4741] += 51.0
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x00D61DF0>, {3277: defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {4733: 54.1}), 3278: defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {4741: 51.0})})
>>>
```

and another approach using a single `defaultdict` with a composite key:

```
>>> d2 = dd(float)
>>> d2[3277,4733] += 54.1
>>> d2
defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {(3277, 4733): 54.1})
>>> d2[3278,4741] += 51.0
>>> d2
defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {(3277, 4733): 54.1, (3278, 4741): 51.0})
>>>
```

*It might help if you were to say what you want to do with this data after you've got it grouped together ...*

If you want (for example) an average, you have two options: (1) two data structures, one for total, one for count, then do "average = total - count" (2) sort your data on the first 2 columns, user itertools.groupby to collect your duplicates together, do your calculation, and add the results into your "average" data structure. Which of these approaches would use less memory is hard to tell; Python being Python you could try both rather quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Indeed what I am looking for is not a contingency table but a mapping of C to A and B in row,column. Thanks for the correction. Hence, I do not need to add up any value but only *position* the values in the correct row/column combination. There are also no repeated keys.  Ideally I am looking for a simple way to transform an input file with A,B,C to an output file with the table.

Answer (score 0):

A small subclasse of dict can provide you a confortable object to work with the table.
500.000 items should not be a problem on a desktop PC - if you happen to have 500.000.000 items, a similar class could map from the keys to positions in the file itself (that would be way more cool to implement :-)  )

```
import csv
class ContingencyTable(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_keys=set()
        self.b_keys=set()
        dict.__init__(self)
    def __setitem__(self, key,value):
        self.a_keys.add(key[0])
        self.b_keys.add(key[1])
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    def feed(self, file):
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        reader.next()
        for a, b, c in reader:
            self[int(a),int(b)] = float(c)

table = ContingencyTable()
table.feed(open("yourfile.csv"))
```